# inbox sql query solution

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok so I am stuck trying to figure out a solution to my user inbox.

Basically when a user views their inbox, I want it to display the last message from each user that has messaged them. So for example, if John messages Jane "message 1", "message 2", "message 3". Jane will see the last message "message 3" in her inbox". My intention is when she clicks the message, she will see the entire thread (which I have squared away). I actually partially have this working but there is a problem. If John then messages Sarah "message 1", "message 2", "message 3" The query will work for Sarah, but will no longer work for Jane.

I can't seem to figure it out. Here is what I have so far. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

```
SELECT t1.*, u.username as from_username, u.user_type as from_usertype, 
     p.profile_picture 
FROM messages t1
JOIN (
    SELECT from_id, MAX(date) date
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY from_id
) t2 ON t1.from_id = t2.from_id AND t1.date = t2.date
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = t1.from_id
LEFT JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = t1.from_id
WHERE t1.to_id = '{$loggeduser}'
    AND t1.deleted = '0'
LIMIT {$pagination->items_per_page}
OFFSET {$pagination->offset}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*,
        u.username as from_username, u.user_type as from_usertype, 
        p.profile_picture 
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                from_id
        FROM    messages
        WHERE   to_id = $loggeduser
                AND deleted = 0
        ) md
JOIN    messages m
ON      m.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    messages mi
        WHERE   mi.to_id = $loggeduser
                AND mi.from_id = md.from_id
                AND mi.deleted = 0
        ORDER BY
                mi.to_id DESC, mi.from_id DESC, mi.date DESC, mi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
JOIN    users u
ON      u.id = md.from_id
JOIN    profiles p
ON      p.user_id = md.from_id
```